# PHP form data not posting after submit

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, post

I'm just starting off with PHP and I've been trying to validate an HTML form and then POST the form's data onto another page, for some reason this doesn't seem to want to work. The issue is that when submit is clicked the page simply refreshes if there are no errors. Here are snippets of the code:

```
<?php
$nameErr = $surnameErr =  " ";
$name = $surname =  " ";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $valid = 0;

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
        $valid++;
    } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
    $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 

    }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["surname"])) {
    $surnameErr = "Surname is required";
    $valid++;
    } else {
    $surname = test_input($_POST["surname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$surname)) {
    $surnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 

    }
    }

    if($valid == 0){
        header('LOCATION: page2.php');
        exit();
    }

}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
```

And here is the HTML

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"> 

<div class="label1">
    <label>First Name</label> 
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John" value="<?php echo $name;?>" onblur="validateName('name')">  

    <label>Surname</label> 
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Smith" value="<?php echo $surname;?>" onblur="validateSurname('surname')"> <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</div>
</form>
```

**page2.php**

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your surname is: <?php echo $_POST["surname"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you can do is change the form action to "page2.php" for the post to be use. And transfer your php codes to page2.php

Comment: @Ralfh changing the form action to "page2.php" posts the data but doesn't validate the form, and transferring the validation code to "page2.php" completely kills the code.

Comment: Try to change this ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") to this (isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: Problem is still going on buddy

Answer (score 1):

When you do your `header('LOCATION: page2.php');` you will loose all your posted data, that will not be available in `page2.php`.

There are several solutions to that, for example:

1. use `include` instead of a `header` redirect;
2. store the posted data in a session or a database so that it is available in other pages.

I don't see any reason why you could not use an `include` here, is there a specific reason you want to redirect?

Comment: Why would i loose the data? Changing the form's action to page2.php posts the data to the next page without a problem, however it doesn't validate the form prior to submitting it.

Comment: @user3649696 When you use a `header` redirect, you request a new script and it will have none of your previously set variables, including the super globals.

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of "Your surname is: <?php echo $_POST["surname"]; ?>", I forgot to include that in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 **main page**

<form method="post" action="page2.php"> 
<div class="label1">
<label>First Name</label> 
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John" onblur="validateName('name')">  

<label>Surname</label> 
<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Smith" onblur="validateSurname('surname')"> <br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
</div>
</form>


**page2.php**
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$valid = 0;

if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$name = "Name is required";
    $valid++;
} else {
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
$name = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
}
    else{$name=$_POST["name"];}
}

if (empty($_POST["surname"])) {
$surname = "Surname is required";
$valid++;
} else {
$surname = test_input($_POST["surname"]);
// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$surname)) {
    $surname = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 

}        else{$surname=$_POST["surname"];}
}

}

function test_input($data) {
 $data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?=$name?><br>
Your surname is: <?=$surname?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Form still submits without validation, even after doing what is shown here.

Comment: what is the output after inputting numbers and  special chars?

Comment: it still submits it, so the issue is that the php validation isn't running? The data is posted to the second page however it is not valid.

Comment: Ofcourse it will submit, the validation occurs after submitting. Try to include a header everytime the inputs are not valid